# yii2 redirect any page to login page after session timeout

Tags: php, yii2

i wanna ask about **redirect any page to login page after session timeout** in yii2, i try to do this

```
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => false,
            'returnUrl' => 'index.php?r=site/login',
            'identityCookie' => [
                'name' => '_backendIdentity',
            ],
        ],

        'session' => [
            'name' => 'BACKENDSESSID',
            'savePath' => __DIR__ . '/../runtime',
        ],
```

but it return to login page when i'm at index.php page, if i go to another action and the session timeout it will return

> PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
>   Trying to get property of non-object

```
1. in /var/www/html/spmoa/backend/controllers/StaffController.php at line 174
165166167168169170171172173174175176177178179180181182183

    public function actionMyProfile() {
       error here ->  $id = Yii::$app->user->identity->staff->id;
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
```

Please help me

Comment: You get this error because the user isn't defined. Do you want to redirect to login page if someone isn't logged in?

Comment: You have to set up the `AccessControl` filter for each action that should require logging in. Try reading this https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-authorization

Comment: @Sfili_81 yes i want it to redirect back to login page

Comment: @MichalHynčica set up access control at controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with behaviors

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [

                [
                    'actions' => ['youraction'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'], // you can use matchCallback to create  more powerful  check 
                ],
            ],
        ], 

    ];`enter code here`
}
```

Comment: if i do this i have to do to al my controller right?

Comment: set in each controller behavior. if you don't know how, you can read it here:
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-filters-accesscontrol

Comment: if it was helpful, please mark if you can, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Please use session and timeout as below in your config/main.php file:

```
'components' => [
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'authTimeout' => 3600*4, // auth expire 4 hours
    ],
    'session' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\Session',
        'cookieParams' => ['httponly' => true, 'lifetime' => 3600*4],
        'timeout' => 3600*4, //session expire 4 hours
        'useCookies' => true,
    ],
],
//and in this beforeRequest give actions that can be accessed by guest user.
'as beforeRequest' => [
    'class' => 'yii\filters\AccessControl',
    'rules' => [
        [
            'allow' => true,
            'actions' => ['login', 'error', 'forgotpassword', 'resetpassword'],
        ],
        [
            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => ['@'],
        ],
    ],
],
```

Comment: let me try first .

Answer (score -1):

You can check condition **Before action** : If user is logged in or not :

```
public function beforeAction($action){

        if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest){
            return $this->redirect(['site/login'])->send();  // login path
        }
    }
```

Comment: or create a controller and extend all from that controller.

Comment: can u please help me about that method extend all from that controller its mean that i need to create another controller that have this function n extend all controller to that function right?